# Taylor expansion - estimates integral remainder term of $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$

Tags: calculus

Integral form of Taylor expansion looks like this:
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}x^i+\int_0^x\frac{f^{(k+1)}(t)}{k!}(x-t)^kdt$$
How can I estimate the remainder term of n-th order for $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$? Then: how to find bounds or estimates for the integral?

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention it, I assume you intend to use the integral form rather than any other form?

To find the remainder term for the $n$-th order approximation to $\cosh(x)$, start by plugging in $k \mapsto n$ and $f \mapsto \cosh$ into your formula for the remainder term. You'll need to use the fact that

$$ \cosh^{(\text{even})} = \cosh \qquad \cosh^{(\text{odd})} = \sinh $$

and you'll probably have to break the problem into cases depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.

(I point this out, since your question suggests you haven't even gotten that far; if you have already understood that part and are having trouble coming up with bounds or estimates for the integral, you should ask a question about how to find bounds or estimates for the integral)

Then anything that makes it hard to integrate, find a bound for it so that you can argue the integral is less than the integral you get by replacing the complicated bit with a constant. Pay attention to the signs of things!

Comment: Yes, it is so, I intend to use the integral form rather than any other form.